# Regular expression on rotten tomatoes URL -- exclude stem

Tags: python, regex, rotten-tomatoes

I want to return a match on a TV series url:

```
YES: http://www.rottentomatoes.com/tv/falling-skies/
```

But not on a TV episode or TV season

```
NO: http://www.rottentomatoes.com/tv/falling-skies/s03
NO: http://www.rottentomatoes.com/tv/falling-skies/s12/e01
```

I currently have the following regex:

```
match = re.match('(http(s)?://)?(www.)?rottentomatoes.com/tv/.+', url)
```

This matches **all** three of the above. How would I construct the regex to only match the first one?

Comment: why have you added `.+` in the end?

Comment: you probably could just replace the `.` by `[^/]+/` (not slash +, then slash)

Comment: @njk not necessarily -- look at the third url, it doesn't have a second slash in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negated character class instead of `.+`:

```
^http://www\.rottentomatoes\.com/tv/[^/]+/?$
```

`[^/]+` matches any character that is not a slash, one or more times — which is everything from `tv/` until the next slash (or the end of the string if a `/` is not present).

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aZ2bQ2/2)

Comment: with `match` the line anchors are not really necessary, since it matches the whole string.

Comment: @njzk2: I think the OP is performing validation. Without the anchors, wouldn't this match `foobarhttp://...` as well?

Comment: no. because `match` requires to match the whole string. try it `re.match('http://', 'foobarhttp://')` returns `None`.

Comment: @njzk2 match implicitly adds a *start* anchor, but not an end anchor.